# Windows batch filename generator not running where am I going wrong?

Tags: windows, batch, csv

I'm writing a windows batch script to take a .csv as input read data in each row as variables and output unique filenames to a new .csv in Windows batch script. I'm doing this to create an inventory of thousands of analog slides I'm converting to digital.

For some reason that I cannot figure out it is not creating the output, If anyone is able to offer some insight on what is going wrong I would really appreciate it.

```
@echo off setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set prefix="MyPrefix" set input_file="input.csv" 
set output_file="filenames.csv" 
set log_file=log.txt

rem Set up logging echo Starting the script > !log_file!

!output_file! ( for /f “skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=,” %%a in (!input_file!) do ( set “box_num=00%%a” set “folder_num=00%%b” set “image_range=%%c” for /l %%i in (1, 1, !image_range!) do ( set “num=000%%i” set “filename=!prefix!_Box!box_num:~-2!_Folder!folder_num:~-2!_image!num:~-4!” echo !filename! ) echo Generated filenames for box !box_num:~-2!, folder !folder_num:~-2!, and image range !image_range! >> !log_file! ) )

echo Finished the script >> !log_file! echo The script has successfully completed.
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 75 |
| 17 | 1 | 71 |
| 17 | 2 | 78 |

Sorry, the site won't let me post a direct paste from excel yet but this identical to it.

Comment: Can you paste a few lines of `input.csv` as well?

Comment: I am not a pro at batch (it seems like a terrible language for this task) but I believe the issue is that you are using delayed expansion (`!var!`) in combination with substring operations (`~`), which per https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html does not function properly with all echo statements. if you don't actually need delayed expansion, try changing your vars back to `%var%`.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of your input.csv and also a screenshot of the desired output.csv?

Comment: @Mastaxx I wish that I could but I can't post a direct screen shot because my account is too new.

Comment: @FrankThomas Heard on batch being terrible, I don't have a ton of scripting experience so if there's a better language to accomplish this I would be interested in your suggestion.

Comment: no point changing direction if you are making progress, but for windows if you do want to stick with shell scripting I'd recommend powershell, and if you are willing to branch out a bit, personally, I'd do this in Python. they both have a much clearer, less arcane syntax that is easier to read, easier to debug, ect. just my two bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "%~dp0"
set "_prefix=.\MyPrefix"
set "_output=.\filenames.csv" 
set "_log=.\log.txt

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (' type .\"input.csv" ') do (
     set "_box=00%%~a"
     set "_folder=00%%~b"
     set "_range=000%%~c"
     for /l %%i in (10001, 00001,10!_range:~-3!) do (
         set "_num=%%~i"
         set "_filename=!_prefix!_Box!_box:~-2!_Folder!_folder:~-2!_image!_num:~-4!"
         echo\!_filename!
        ) 
         echo Generated filenames for box !_box:~-2!, folder !_folder:~-2!, and image range !_range:~-4!
    )

endlocal
```

---

> *"For some reason that I cannot figure out it is not creating the output, If anyone is able to offer some insight on what is going wrong I would really appreciate it."*

Your redirect **`>here.csv ( commands ... >>here_too.log)`** which will be chosen by the command interpreter?

So, rethink what you want on the screen and what you want in the **`.csv`** file and what you want in the **`.log`** file, but understand that the interpreter does not offer multiplicity redirections to std_out (stderr doesn't either).

Prioritize correct code execution, then separate `>>` appending a `.csv`, and/or `>>` appending a `.log`

---

From what I could understand, what goes to the screen, and what goes to the file, you can use a "trick" and make the response line on the screen using:

```
>some.txt ( 
   command 
   command
   >con: echo/ out this on screen
  )
```

- What results in this suggestion:

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_log=.\log.txt 
set "_prefix=.\MyPrefix"
set "_output=.\filenames.csv" 

2>nul del /q /f /a: .\"filenames.csv"

for /f skip^=1^tokens^=1-3^delims^=^, %%a in =;(' type .\"input.csv"
    ');= do >>.\filenames.csv =;(
     set "_box=00%%~a"
     set "_folder=00%%~b"
     set "_range=000%%~c"
     for /l %%i in =;( 10001,00001,10!_range:~-3! );= do =;(
         set "_num=%%~i"
         set "_filename=!_prefix!_Box!_box:~-2!_Folder!_folder:~-2!_image!_num:~-4!"
         echo\!_filename!
        );= 
     @=>con: echo Generated filenames for box !_box:~-2!, folder !_folder:~-2!, and image range !_range:~-4!
    );=

endlocal
```

Comment: @lo-ol Thank you for that, it is now generating an output file but only for final line of data on the input.csv. Now I need to get it to loop through every row that contains data in the .csv

Comment: so, see: `>last_line.csv` and `>>all_lines.csv`

Comment: Got it to do what I needed it to do by moving the >> .\."filenames.csv" to the end of the for command. Thanks for your help!

Comment: consider trying with powershell, after all it doesn't bite!